# how to flip the video taken using front camera android

Tags: android, video, camera, front-camera

I have a video that mirror flips when I take it using the front camera.

The surface view that is used to capture the video shows the mirror effect when recording but then it is flipped while playing the same.

Kindly Help me.

Comment: please explain your question i didn't get your point.

Answer (score 2):

This is an expected behavior. You cannot run the video recorder mirrored. You can flip the frames yourself (receiving the frames in onPreviewFrame callback) and use MediaCodec and her kin to produce a video file on your own. Or you can post-process your video, e.g. with **ffmpeg**.

Comment: I have post processed using ffmpeg