# Android Front Camera flip the video recorded using MediaRecorder

Tags: android, video, flip, android-mediarecorder

Is there a method to flip the video recorded by front camera using MediaRecorder? Now the preview is showing mirror view and the recorded output is the flipped version of preview. I want the mirrored preview to be recorded like the SnapChat Application. I have tried [MediaRecorder.setOrientationHint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setOrientationHint%28int%29) but it is not mirroring the preview. I dont want to post process the video like this:
[how to flip the video taken using front camera android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37299449/how-to-flip-the-video-taken-using-front-camera-android)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, the frontal camera always records the image flipped and then adds a meta tag to the video indicating that the rotation is 180. That's the same that orientationHint does.

The problem in this approach is that many player doesn't care about this metadata and show the image flipped.

If recording and playing happens inside your application, a simpler solution is to use a TextureView to reproduce your video and apply a transformation matrix to rotate it.

Comment: `Flipping` and `Rotation` is not the same thing.